# Induced Galois Action on Modular Curve

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

In my reading about modular curves, the author states that a certain group $G$ acts on the function field $K$ of the modular curve $X_1(N)$, hence it acts on $X_1(N)$ itself. What is this induced action? I cannot think of anything particularly natural. Is there always a natural action of a group $G$ on a curve $X$ if $G$ acts on $K(X)$?

Comment: The category of smooth curves over an algebraically closed field $k$ is equivalent to the category of finitely generated extensions of $k$ with transcendence degree $1$. (This should be in Chapter I of Hartshorne)

Comment: That is true, but the explicit action is what I am after.

Comment: You should just read about the equivalence that Kenta S referenced. Choose an affine open $V=\mathrm{Spec}(A)\subseteq X_1(N)$. Then, observe that $g\in\mathrm{Aut}_k(X)$ defines a map $g|_A:A\to K(X)$ and one can easily check that the image must land in $B$ for some affine open $U=\mathrm{Spec}(B)\subseteq X$. So then, one gets a map $g:U\to V$ induced by this map of $k$-algebras. By the valuative criterion (or curve to projective extension theorem -- whatever you want to call it) this extends uniquely to $g:X\to X$. This is independent of all choices. You just do this for all $g\in G$.

Comment: Without telling us the action, and in general, that's about all you can say.

Comment: @Johnny Apple Out of interest, which book are you reading?